# Archaeologists Time Travel to King Arthur Times

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I remember reading a book about a group of archaeologists who are on a dig, they find a building, and they end up traveling back to what I believe was Arthurian times by way of something they found. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: Add some more details so that it is easier to identify

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing [*Timeline* (2003)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0300556/):

> A group of archaeologists become trapped in the past when they go there to retrieve a friend. The group must survive in 14th century France before they can escape back to the 21st Century.

One detail I remember about this movie is that:

> An unknown king whose tomb shows a chopped off/damaged ear later turns out to be one of the time-travelers whose ear gets chopped off.

Comment: He's asking about a book. But I agree that Timeline sounds like a match. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_(novel)

Comment: 14th century France? I would have thought "Arthurian times" was a few centuries earlier than that.

Comment: @ShadeOfGrey Yeah I realised that after I already posted the answer. I tried looking for a book version of the movie but couldn't find it.

Comment: @user14111 This was a painful way to find out I'm terrible at history.

Comment: @ShadeOfGrey the film is based on a book of the same name by Michael Crichton. Pretty poor as I recall. Not sure if this is what the OP is thinking of though.

Answer (score 2):

I can recall a novel with the same plot, The bones of Charlemagne, by [Mario Pei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Pei).
Of course it is not a book, being a short story (so probably Timeline is the correct answer).

I read it in an anthology cured by Isaac Asimov, [Great Science Fiction Stories by the World's Greatest Scientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Science_Fiction_by_Scientists) (in the Wikipedia page it isn't listed among the featured works, so maybe it was added in a later edition); unluckily the only refernce I could find online is [this one, in Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=39KQY1FnSfkC&lpg=PA16&ots=EAgYbw1OKn&dq=the%20bones%20of%20charlemagne%20pei&hl=it&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=the%20bones%20of%20charlemagne%20pei&f=false)

From what I remember

- In the story, a linguist (Mario Pei himself) is sent in the past together with a colleague
- They call themselves by Latin names (Peius and Cantabricus, since the surname of the colleague was "Irish") and say that come from Armorica
- They are welcome in the court of Charlemagne and make friends with his sons

> - But at some point, they are in trouble because their oddities make people think they are some kind of demons